# A manifest file in one of your active artifacts doesn't include the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have already declared the `AD_ID` permission in my manifest but I am still getting the following error in the Google Play Console:

> Your advertising ID declaration in Play Console says that your app uses advertising ID. A manifest file in one of your active artifacts doesn't include the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTNA1.png) is a screenshot of the error.

Here is my manifest:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/splash_theme"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".WebActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".DetailActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxx"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```